# Save programatically UTF-8 and C#

Tags: c#, encoding

How to save programatically a file in UTF-8 with Signature 65001?

Comment: Do you mean Codepage 65001? It is the same as UTF-8. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_65001

Answer (score 2):

65001 means the same thing as UTF-8.  Just use a StreamWriter, it formats text in UTF-8 by default.